# SOQL querying url addresses

Tags: javascript, rest, salesforce, soql

I'm struggling to get the right SOQL query in a way that I can search and filter by URL addresses, through the API.

We have a custom field `Crunchbase_URL__c`, which can be both written by my application (usign the REST API), or filled in manually by the user.

Most of the times, when the URL was filled automatically, the line

```
.../services/data/v47.0/query?q=SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Crunchbase_URL__c = 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/{the permalink that I'm searching}'
```

will work without any issues, but sometimes when the user would only type `www.crunchbase.com/....` without the `https` the query obviously comes back empty.

I tried to use `LIKE` instead of the `=` operator, but it looks like it would only work with a string beginning with the query term. So

```
SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Crunchbase_URL__c LIKE '%crunchbase.com/....'
```

is not working.

Currently my workaround is to query for all the possibilities (from my Javascript code):

```
"Crunchbase_URL__c = 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/" + Sel_row.QueryName + "'" +
                            " OR Crunchbase_URL__c = 'https://crunchbase.com/organization/" + Sel_row.QueryName + "'" +
                            " OR Crunchbase_URL__c = 'http://www.crunchbase.com/organization/" + Sel_row.QueryName + "'" +
                            " OR Crunchbase_URL__c = 'http://crunchbase.com/organization/" + Sel_row.QueryName + "'" +
                            " OR Crunchbase_URL__c = 'crunchbase.com/organization/" + Sel_row.QueryName + "'" +
                            " OR Crunchbase_URL__c = 'www.crunchbase.com/organization/" + Sel_row.QueryName + "' "
```

but this hardly looks like the right approach.

Furthermore, when querying for the standard Website field I have exactly the same issues.

I've also thought of querying for all the Accounts and then do the filter in Google Apps Script (it's a custom add-on), but that also doesn't seem the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm):

> The % wildcard (in a WHERE ... LIKE ... clause)  matches zero or more characters

You have to allow that there may be characters after the term you are searching for.

For example, `'%ell%'` matches a record 'hello'. But `'%ell'` does not.

You should be able to use `'%://%cruchbase.com/%some-query-term%'` where some-query-term matches exactly how the string appears in the URL.

Can you give an example of a URL and the query you expect to retrieve it that is not working?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had in the beginning, and then I saw some empty queries and started to dig deeper.  I just tried `https://myorg.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/query?q=SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Crunchbase_URL__c LIKE '%crunchbase.com/organization/tesla-motors%'` but I'm receiving a 400 bad request through Postman :S

Comment: I have a record with a  Crunchbase_URL__c field: **crunchbase.com/organization/tesla-motors**

Comment: just tried with workbench, and looks like it's working. Wondering if Postman was encoding it in a weird way.